Getting different result from same Paddle model on CPU and GPU
I'm currently facing an issue and would greatly appreciate any assistance you can offer.
I have a paddleOCR model that I'm serving through a Docker image based on version 2.5.1 of the paddlepaddle/paddle image. On one workstation, it works well with the 'use_gpu' attribute set to True or False. However, on another workstation, the outputs of the model are incorrect when it runs on GPU. I have attached the results of the model in both situations.
CPU result: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/assets/48449058/cd8d88f6-535c-4a94-9227-5631dfce8c22
GPU result: https://github.com/PaddlePaddle/PaddleOCR/assets/48449058/4d0d1010-a69f-4da5-8e75-4e081c333624
It appears that the computation of the model is incorrect when it's running on GPU. It's important to note that I'm not encountering any errors or warnings, just inaccurate results.
Some additional context:

This issue did not occur with version 2.4 of the Paddle library, but I need to upgrade my Paddle version.
The images above show the result of the text detection model, but I've had the same experience with the text recognition and layout models as well.

Thank you in advance for any insights or suggestions you can provide.
I have attempted to make the environments of the two workstations as similar as possible, but due to them having different GPUs (3090 Ti and Tesla P40), achieving complete parity is not feasible. And while it runs on Docker, I'm not sure how the host effect on the reult of the model on container.
What could be the root cause of this inconsistency?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
